# Remove garbage character from String

Tags: android, regex

In my Android Application when I am reading the particular data from NFC chip it's giving garbage values as show follows which is printed on Log

����������������

I used following line to remove garbage value

```
str.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "")
```

but it is not working.

Please provide me solution.

Comment: Please show your real code. Why do you expect that reading data from a hardware chip gives printable ASCII characters?

Answer (score 2):

That is because `�` is not an `ASCII` character. It is a unicode character with `(int) �` returning `65533`.

And your code `str.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "")` works perfectly fine.

```
scala> val str ="����������������"
str: String = ����������������

scala> str.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "")
res8: String = ""
```

You need to show more code and explain what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: @nhahtdh, yes, but that code should still work to eliminate any non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

Better to retrieve the data in the form of UTF-8 format then it helps. try it out.

or convert the string to UTF-8 format

i.e, `String _data=new String(str.getBytes(),"UTF-8");`

it returns the data in UTF-8 format

Comment: It sounds like the OP is reading binary data.  If so, UTF-8 isn't going to help.

Answer (score 0):

One solution using this method `.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "")`

```
String str = "jorgesys���������������� was here!";
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", ""));
```

so the result of `str` is:

```
jorgesys was here!
```